# Updating huge amount of rows

Tags: sql, oracle, performance, sql-update

I got two tables TESTING and TESTING_BCK, both with the same columns. 
E.g.

**TESTING**

```
NR | KEY1 | KEY2 | ... | KEY7 | COMMENTS
 1  |  ...                     | example1
 1  |  ...                     | example2
 ..... and thousands with NR = 1 more
 2  |  ...                     |  null
 2  |  ...                     |  null
 ..... and again many many more
```

**TESTING_BCK**

```
NR | KEY1 | KEY2 | ... | KEY7 | COMMENTS
 2  |  ...                     |  example
 2  |  ...                     |  'this should go to TESTING'
 ..... and again many many more
```

Now I want to update TESTING so the COMMENTS of TESTING_BCK will be the COMMENTS of TESTING too (based on the keys). I know that all entries in TESTING_BCK definitely have an entry in TESTING with the same keys and NR.
So far I did this like this:

```
UPDATE TESTING
SET COMMENTS = (
        SELECT COMMENTS
        FROM TESTING_BCK
        WHERE TESTING_BCK.NR = TESTING.NR
            AND TESTING_BCK.KEY1 = TESTING.KEY1.....TESTING_BCK.KEY7 = TESTING.KEY7
        )
WHERE EXISTS (
        SELECT COMMENTS
        FROM TESTING_BCK
        WHERE TESTING_BCK.NR = TESTING.NR
            AND TESTING_BCK.KEY1 = TESTING.KEY1
            AND...
        )
```

But this takes forever when I do this with many thousands of entries. Any ideas how I could update TESTING otherwise?

Result should be:

**TESTING**

```
    NR | KEY1 | KEY2 | ... | KEY7 | COMMENTS
     1  |  ...                     | example1
     1  |  ...                     | example2
     ..... and thousands with NR = 1 more
     2  |  ...                     |  example
     2  |  ...                     |  'this should go to TESTING'
     2  |  ...                     |  comment from TESTING_BCK
     ......
```

Comment: not sure what "forever" means (an hour, a day, 12 weeks, etc), but is this a one time update?  Or is this meant to run on some schedule/frequency?

Comment: What indexes do you have?  If we're really just talking about thousands of rows and more than a couple seconds of elapsed time, my guess is that you're missing indexes and constraints on the tables.

Comment: @tbone This is meant to run frequently. I mean with "forever" that it takes several minutes for 10.000 entries, but I normally have millions which will takes "forever". I am trying to improve the performance as much as I can.

Comment: @JustinCave Thanks, I got some constraints on the table but I'm going to look for further ones and also check the indexes.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should use

```
UPDATE 
(SELECT TESTING.COMMENTS as OLD, TESTING_BCK.COMMENTS as NEW
 FROM TESTING
 INNER JOIN TESTING_BCK
 ON TESTING_BCK.NR = TESTING.NR AND TESTING_BCK.KEY1 = TESTING.KEY1 ..... TESTING_BCK.KEY7 = TESTING.KEY7
) t
SET t.OLD = t.NEW
```

Comment: But that doesn't update TESTING, does it? The table "t" is not a real table.

Comment: This qeury should update the rows of the resulting table  . that mapping the real table .. so should work .. based on ORACLE sintax .. .

Comment: I think you misunderstood me. I want to update TESTING and no other table. When I said "The result should be:" I meant that TESTING should look like this after updating. Or did I misunderstood you now, because that query doesn't work when I try it.

Comment: 01779. 00000 -  "cannot modify a column which maps to a non key-preserved table"
*Cause:    An attempt was made to insert or update columns of a join view which
           map to a non-key-preserved table.
*Action:   Modify the underlying base tables directly

Comment: This kind of error is because  in the case of the query proposed Oracle cannot guarantee that there is exactly on match between the rows in each table so the only way for update .. is the one you provided .. this mean that are not possible ..performance improvement  .. ( if you have already setted proper index .. otherwise  .. set proper redundenced index for both the table)